# Use an attribute or association attribute in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails Concern `ExtendedEvent` that I'm using to encapsulate logic relating to events that have a start time and an end time, of which I have several in my application. It currently looks like this:

Usage in a class usually looks like:

```
class InAndOutEvent < ApplicationRecord

  include ExtendedEvent

  def configure_extended_event
    @ee_start_date_time = enter_date_time
    @ee_end_date_time = exit_date_time
  end
end
```

Where `enter_date_time` and `exit_date_time` are model attributes. However, an alternative usage would be something like this:

```
class InAndOutEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: entry
  belongs_to: exit

  include ExtendedEvent

  def configure_extended_event
    @ee_start_date_time = entry.date_time
    @ee_end_date_time = exit.date_time
  end
end
```

Oh, and it's possible that my `entry` and `exit` associations are actually of the same class, which will mean using aliases in queries:

```
  belongs_to :entry, class_name: "ThingWithDateTime"
  belongs_to :exit, class_name: "ThingWithDateTime"
```

I want to define a class-level scope or finder method that will allow me to find models that include `ExtendedEvent` based on whether or not they overlap with a given time range `start_time..end_time`. In obviously broken pseudocode:

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module ExtendedEvent
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def overlaps_with(time_range)
      where(ee_start_date_time: time_range)
        .or(self.where(ee_end_date_time: time_range))
    end
  end

  # ... instance methods as above omitted

end
```

I know it's not possible to use a generic method like this, but my start/end times are set by model attributes, so it feels like this should be possible. If my attribute were always on the model I could replace defining the instance variables with `alias_attribute` and use that perhaps, like:

```
alias_attribute :ee_start_time, :enter_date_time
```

but I don't think that would work with an attribute on the association.

Is there any way of achieving this? I'm using Rails 5.1 on Ruby 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to use `where` if you are searching in the fields from the database, and so, in this case, you have to use plain ruby (which is going to be slow):

```
def self.overlaps_with(time_range)
  select do |instance|
    time_range.include?(instance.ee_start_date_time)
    || time_range.include?(instance.ee_end_date_time)
  end
end
```

Also, if you need an ActiveRecord_Relation instead of array (so you can use methods like `where` on it later) you can do it like this:

```
def self.overlaps_with(time_range)
  ids = select do |instance|
    time_range.include?(instance.ee_start_date_time)
    || time_range.include?(instance.ee_end_date_time)
  end.map(&:id)

  where(id: ids)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should emphasise though that I will always be searching against a database field, but that field might be related to the table for the model that includes ExtendedEvent with a join.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the models you've pasted are relevant for querying the db, so I'll use examples of my own:

```rb
time_range = [1.hour.ago, 1.hour.since]

overlap_records = Model.where('? > models.end_time OR models.start_time < ?', *time_range)

associated_overlap_recs = Assoc.joins(:model).where('? > models.end_time OR models.start_time < ?', *time_range)
```

Make sure the two time columns are compound indexed.

---

So assuming there are:

```rb
class InAndOutEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry, class_name: "ThingWithDateTime"
  belongs_to :exit, class_name: "ThingWithDateTime"
end

class ThingWithDateTime < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You should be able to do something like this:

```rb
# data "from the association"
entry_time = thing_with_date_time_foo.date_time
exit_time = thing_with_date_time_bar.date_time

# to adhere to your api that accepts a `time_range` parameter
time_range = [entry_time, exit_time]
InAndOutEvent.joins(:entry, :exit).where(
  '? > thing_with_date_times.date_time OR thing_with_date_times_in_and_out_events.start_time < ?',
  *time_range
)
```

The specific query depends on the [table aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) ActiveRecord "chooses" for the join.

It gets quite more complicated if one or both of the associations are polymorphic.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right that my examples were broken. I've fixed them to hopefully clarify things a bit.

Comment: `entry` and `exit` are polymorphic?

Comment: I'd prefer not to assume they're of the same class, but in practice they are yes.

Comment: No, that'd mean the opposite of "polymorphic". 1) `entry` can can be a `Foo` and `exit` can be a `Bar`? or 2) f `entry` is a `Foo`, `exit` will be a `Foo` also, and vice versa? 3) In the code, how many `entry` types are there? Only a particular "`Foo`" or multiple types?

Comment: Like I said, I would prefer to assume that they are not of the same class if possible. But in practice, my only examples so far would have them of the same class.

Comment: If they're not going to be static and predetermined, same class or not, I'm not sure Rails can "magically do it for you", and you'll have to pretty much write SQL in some form. I'll answer in the case that they are going to be static and predetermined.

Comment: Yeah, tbh I'm leaning towards denormalising my tables and coming up with something based on `alias_attribute`.

Comment: Not sure how `alias_attribute` can help, but I highly recommend against denormalizing. The data model looks okay so far, and a RDBMS can handle and query this like a breeze if left normalized -- it's just two indexed `<` checks. The "limitation" is that ActiveRecord struggles with anything other than trivial tree-shaped associations.